# How to extend BitBake class

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm building an image with Yocto, and need to patch a BitBake class in the upstream tree. I do not want to modify the upstream sources and would prefer to add the modification to a local layer.

For a BitBake **recipe**, I'd use a `.bbappend` file. What should be used for a **class**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create `classes` folder in your meta layer and create a new class, e.g. `myclass.bbclass`. Inherit original class with `inherit original-bitbake-CLASS` and add whatever functionality you need.

Then use the new bbclass instead of the original.

Comment: For the record, this doesn't work. I created in my meta later `classes-recipe/kernel.bbclass` and simply placed two lines: `inherit kernel` and `NEW_DEFINE = "abc"`. The yocto kernel recipe is using by default `kernel.bbclass`, and since my layer has priority, it is loading my version. But, it is not inheriting `kernel.bbclass` from openembedded like this post suggests it would. I get a simple error that proves that: `ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'virtual/kernel'`

Answer (score 7):

@lukaszgard method works except for one minor issue. **BBFILE_PRIORITY** does not provide override capability for bbclass and conf files, it only works for recipes (.bb). This is based on a section of the Yocto manual, [Prioritizing Your Layer](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#prioritizing-your-layer) where it says

> Note: It is possible for a recipe with a lower version number PV in a layer that has a higher priority to take precedence.
> **Also, the layer priority does not currently affect the precedence order of .conf or .bbclass files.** Future versions of BitBake might address this.

A method I found that works is to create a bblayer, create and apply changes of the required bbclass and then in **/build/conf/bblayers.conf**, place the created bblayer above the layer that you are trying to override.

This is based on another section of the [Yocto manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#adding-a-layer-using-the-bitbake-layers-script) which says

> Note: During a build, the OpenEmbedded build system looks in the layers from the top of the list down to the bottom in that order.

An example:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/<layer with new bbclass> \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/<layer with old bbclass> \
"
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally with *.bbclass* files there is lack of similar approach like we have with appending recipes (.bbappends). Proposed by @Oleksandr-Kravchuk solution is good but have some limitations. When You have to modify some functions or makes more complex changes, then I would prefer to copy this class file to my metadata layer and make adaptations there. Finally *bitbake* based on configuration in layer (conf/layer.conf file) - [BBFILE_PRIORITY](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-BBFILE_PRIORITY) will decide to take this class file comes from layer with higher priority lever - **without touching recipes**.